# added footer view to list activity listview but it doesn't show

Tags: android, listview

i have a xml file for footer view with a textview inside it, i have inflated the footer view and extracted textview from it, then i added it to list activity's list view as footer view but it doesn't show when i run it. here is the code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
TextView footer=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footer);
getListView().addFooterView(footer);
```

and here is the xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="@string/footer_text"
android:textColor="#0000FF"
android:textSize="20sp" />
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Make sure you call `addFooterView()` before you call `setAdapter()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your footer view like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
TextView footer = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, getListView(), false);
getListView().addFooterView(footer);
```

Update: Just looked up how I did it in one of my projects, so this should work as well:

```
TextView footer = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, getListView(), false);
getListView().addFooterView(footer);
```

Comment: Thank you :) a lot :) this correct too but Karakuri's answer solved the problem  :)